# WebRtc .Net implementation

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, cordova, p2p

I write p2p audio call app, using cordova and Peer.js for one type of client over WebRtc and i want to use .Net implementation for WinForms for another clients. Need free solution, because it is experemental app, not commercial. If it exist, please say me.

P.S. I found only paid solution. Thank in advance!

Comment: Which paid solution did you find?